# Visual Studio: How to store an image resource as an Embedded Resource?

Tags: visual-studio, image

By default when you add an image (icon, bitmap, etc.) as a resource to your project, the image's **Build Action** is set to **None**. This is done because the image is magically stored inside a .resources file.

***I*** want the resource to be stored as an embedded resource (my reasons are irrelevant, but let's just pretend it's so that I can see them inside **[RedGate's Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/)**).

So I changed each image's **Build Action** to **Embedded Resource**, and the resource then appears inside Lutz's Reflector - exactly as I want.

**Unfortunately**, [Microsoft says specifically not to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(VS.80).aspx):

> Note that when the resource editor
>   adds an image, it sets **Build Action** to
>   **None**, because the .resx file
>   references the image file. At build
>   time, the image is pulled into the
>   .resources file created out of the
>   .resx file. The image can then easily
>   be accessed via the strongly-typed
>   class auto-generated for the .resx
>   file.
>
> Therefore, you should not change
>   this setting to **Embedded Resource**,
>   because doing so would include the
>   image twice in the assembly.

So what is the **proper way** to include an image as an embedded resource?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

***Note: This answer is not the recommended way of handling image resources. It just addresses the particular problem as described by the question (i.e. to include an image as an embedded resourse).***

Don't add the image as a resource. I would rather do the following:

- Create the image/icon and save it to a file
- Choose Project -> Add Existing Item and add the file
- Set the Build Action to Embedded Resource

You can then access this resource using

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceUri)
```

This way the image is *not* magically added to the projects resource file and you will only have one copy of the image stored in the assembly's resources.

Comment: This sounds like a good answer, but i'll have to wait to test it before i can accept it.

Comment: The disadvantage to this solution is that you won't get the autogenerated name for the resource (e.g., in VB .NET, My.Resources.NameOfYourImage.  But if that doesn't bother you, then it's probably the best solution.

Comment: But since the OP definitely wants the resource stored as an Embedded Resource, I guess that he has to access it using the GetManifestResourceStream methods

Comment: However please note that this makes the image non-localizable. Todd's answer explains this well.

Comment: If you're Getting a ManifestResourcesStream, 99% of the time you're doing it wrong.  I hate seeing this out there because noobs might try to handle resources this way rather than via the property editor.

Comment: @Will: I agree that the solution described by my answer is generally not the preferred way of handling image resources. I added an explanatory note at the beginning.

Comment: @Will - It would be nice (for us noobs :) to have a link to the "right way" (if such a link exists).

Answer (score 15):

In the project view, open the Properties subtree; double-click the Resources.resx item.

(If you don't have one, right-click the Properties item and choose Open, then click on the Resources tab on the left, and click the link in the middle of the page to create a default resources file.)

click the first droplist at the top of the resources.resx page. It probably says something unhelpful like "Strings", and select Images. Alternately you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>. This changes to the Image resources view. Now click the Add Resource droplist and choose 'existing file'. Select your image file and click Open. Rename the resource if you like.

Click the Save icon.

You can now access your embedded resource programmatically as:

```
[namespace].Properties.Resources.[yourResourceName]
```

Answer (score 6):

In VS 2005:

- Right click on your project and
  choose add new item.
- Add a resource file. Call is
  ***myImages.resx***
  *Place this file in the root folder of the project.*
- Right click on ***myImages.resx***
  and choose View Designer
- Select Add Resource, Add Existing
  file.
- Browse for the image e.g. ***stop.bmp***
  *This image does not have to be included in the project at this stage. The resource file will automatically do this.*

To reference the image in code use something like:

```
btnStop.Image = myImages.Stop;
```

Answer (score 5):

This depends on how you want to use the image.

If you want to localize and access specific images for a specific culture, then using the `ResourceManager` is a good way to go because it provides some nice functionality for satellite assemblies, searching, fallbacks, etc.

If you just want to embed a resource in an assembly and aren't worried about localization (using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`) then just adding a image and setting the build action to `Embedded Resource` is fine.

The documentation warns you about not setting the build action to `Embedded Resource` because the resource is already compiled into the assembly by the resource compiler via the .resx file.

Comment: But how do you set the Build Action to Embedded Resource, and not have it double included?